# CORS error between front and back-end both deployed on Heroku

Tags: vue.js, heroku, fastapi

I have fastapi backend that is deployed on heroku.

Then I have a vueJs frontend... when I run my frontend on localhost, it consumes my deployed backend as intended. But when I run the hereoku deployed frontend, it triggers a CORS error.

```
[Error] Not allowed to request resource
    (fonction anonyme) (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:905:5476)
    Promise
    (fonction anonyme) (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:905:3329)
    (fonction anonyme) (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:905:9926)
    (fonction anonyme) (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:905:8256)
    (fonction anonyme) (app.300a0e8b.js:1:8475)
    asyncFunctionResume
    re (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:2282:11801)
    Fn (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:2282:29361)
    insert (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:2282:21037)
    O (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:2282:48055)
    (fonction anonyme) (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:2282:49366)
    (fonction anonyme) (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:2282:27206)
    i (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:2282:28010)
    (fonction anonyme) (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:2282:30902)
    ri (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:2282:30819)
    Dn (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:2282:28033)
    (fonction anonyme) (app.300a0e8b.js:1:9836)
    promiseReactionJob

[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://test-api.herokuapp.com/api/v3 due to access control checks.
    (fonction anonyme) (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:905:5476)
    Promise
    (fonction anonyme) (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:905:3329)
    (fonction anonyme) (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:905:9926)
    (fonction anonyme) (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:905:8256)
    (fonction anonyme) (app.300a0e8b.js:1:8475)
    asyncFunctionResume
    re (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:2282:11801)
    Fn (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:2282:29361)
    insert (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:2282:21037)
    O (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:2282:48055)
    (fonction anonyme) (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:2282:49366)
    (fonction anonyme) (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:2282:27206)
    i (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:2282:28010)
    (fonction anonyme) (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:2282:30902)
    ri (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:2282:30819)
    Dn (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:2282:28033)
    (fonction anonyme) (app.300a0e8b.js:1:9836)
    promiseReactionJob

[Error] Not allowed to request resource
    (fonction anonyme) (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:905:5476)
    Promise
    (fonction anonyme) (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:905:3329)
    (fonction anonyme) (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:905:9926)
    (fonction anonyme) (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:905:8256)
    (fonction anonyme) (app.300a0e8b.js:1:8592)
    asyncFunctionResume
    (fonction anonyme)
    promiseReactionJobWithoutPromise
    promiseReactionJob

[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://test-api.herokuapp.com/api/v2 due to access control checks.
    (fonction anonyme) (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:905:5476)
    Promise
    (fonction anonyme) (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:905:3329)
    (fonction anonyme) (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:905:9926)
    (fonction anonyme) (chunk-vendors.dadb741b.js:905:8256)
    (fonction anonyme) (app.300a0e8b.js:1:8592)
    asyncFunctionResume
    (fonction anonyme)
    promiseReactionJobWithoutPromise
    promiseReactionJob
```

I have set my CORS on the backend like this :

```
origins = [
    "https://test-front.herokuapp.com",
    "http://16.11.192.108:8080/",
    "http://localhost",
    "http://localhost:8080",
]


app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

My frontend api calls are like this :

```
await axios.get('http://test-api.herokuapp.com/api/v3')
      .then(response => (this.apiInfoV3 = response.data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Comment: What does this address ("http://16.11.192.108:8080/") refer to? Frontend IP address?

Comment: What your frontend's IP is is unclear, but I see two potential issues. 1) `http://16.11.192.108:8080/` is not a [Web origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin); drop that trailing slash. 2) You're hitting the so-called _wildcard exception_; see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards. In brief, you cannot use `*` is you allow credentials.

Comment: Are you sure this is a CORS problem - I see the `due to access control checks` text in the errors, but could that be something other than CORS (I admit that I'm used to seeing CORS errors in the browser so the text may vary). While @jub0bs is correct in their analysis of your configuration errors, I would suggest that rather than hardcode allowed values for the Origin request header, you simply retrieve the Origin request header and return it ('mirror it back') in the ACAO response header - much simpler for testing purposes.

Comment: @roryhewitt Reflecting arbitrary origins in ACAO is insecure.

Comment: @jub0bs, which is why I explicitly mentioned "testing purposes".

As to how 'insecure' mirroring back incoming origins is, that's debatable. The vast majority of CORS scenarios don't care about the site - they simply occur due to the asset origin being different from the page origin. Sure, there are some cases where the app will actually check the Origin header value, but those are honestly few and far between. My (extensive!) experience is that, certainly during testing on something like Heroku, just return the Origin header. Long term, CORS is not a security mechanism to be relied on.

Comment: @roryhewitt See https://portswigger.net/research/exploiting-cors-misconfigurations-for-bitcoins-and-bounties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As silly as it seems, what did the trick was simply to add an "s" to `http` in `http://test-api.herokuapp.com/api/v3` like this:

```
await axios.get('https://test-api.herokuapp.com/api/v3')...
```